# How to turn an object into an array with JavaScript?

Tags: reactjs, redux

i´m trying to return the data from the bookstore API, i can add the data and i see the data in the code inspector, but for some reason it doesn´t show on my project.

```html
import axios from 'axios';
import { createAsyncThunk } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

export const postApiData = axios.post('https://us-central1-bookstore-api-e63c8.cloudfunctions.net/bookstoreApi/apps/');

export const currentApiKey = 'gwE0Bhw9RcasmYxC9anP';

export const uploadBookThunk = createAsyncThunk(
  'uploadBook',
  async (book) => {
    const res = await axios.post(`https://us-central1-bookstore-api-e63c8.cloudfunctions.net/bookstoreApi/apps/${currentApiKey}/books`, {
      item_id: book.item_id,
      title: book.title,
      author: book.author,
      category: book.category,
    });
    return res.json();
  },
);

export const getBookDataThunk = createAsyncThunk(
  'books/getBookData',
  async () => {
    const res = await axios.get(`https://us-central1-bookstore-api-e63c8.cloudfunctions.net/bookstoreApi/apps/${currentApiKey}/books`)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data);
      });
    console.log(res.json());
    return res.json();
  },
);

const createBookList = (book) => {
  const bookList = [];
  book.forEach((item) => {
    bookList.push(item);
  });
  return bookList;
};

export const getBooks = createAsyncThunk(
  'books/getBooks',
  async () => {
    const response = await axios.get(`https://us-central1-bookstore-api-e63c8.cloudfunctions.net/bookstoreApi/apps/${currentApiKey}/books`)
      .then((response) => response.data);
    return createBookList(response);
  },
);
```

i know i have a prblem on the getbook data funtion but i can´t figure out were.

Comment: yeah i have a sandbox where i making test on the project but still have the same issue

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-cerf-59f417?file=/.gitignore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you get an object from the API and you want an array.

## How to turn an object into an array ?

Let's say you have the following object:

```json
{
    "1": { color: "blue" },
    "2": { color: "green" }
}
```

And you want the following array:

```json
[
   { color: "blue" },
   { color: "green" }
]
```

You can use [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) which give you each value of an object.

```js
const input = {
    "1": { color: "blue" },
    "2": { color: "green" }
};

const output = Object.values(input);

console.log(output);
```

### Which change to do in your project ?

You have to change the function into this:

```
const createBookList = (books) => {
  const bookList = [];
  Object.values(books).forEach((item) => {
    bookList.push(item[0]);
  });
  return bookList;
};
```

In your current implementation of **createBookList** you expect to get an array.
But the api returns an object, where each key is an id, and each value is an array of one item (The book)

This is how the API response looks like:

```json
{
    "6Q_FDyPxJIQjKE23ZKQFx": [
        {
            title: "Eminence in Shadow"
            category: "Undetermined"
            author: "Daisuke Aizawa"
        }
    ],
    "0HdytC63SPlQjV2d7KP-N": [
        {
            author: "Mafujin Na Magonote"
            category: "Undetermined"
            title: "Jobless Reincarnation"
        }
    ]
}
```

Then instead of using [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), which is not possible with an object. You use [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) which give you each values of an object. Then you iterate on it with [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) (because you now have an array instead of an object). The you keep only the first element of the array to create a new array.

```js
const createBookList = (books) => {
  const bookList = [];
  Object.values(books).forEach((item) => {
    bookList.push(item[0]);
  });
  return bookList;
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Julien you fix mi issue, I apreciate it your help.